# Subset data based on vector with repeated observations

Tags: r, subset

I have the following data with two observations per subject:

```
SUBJECT <- c(8,8,10,10,11,11,15,15)
POSITION <- c("H","L","H","L","H","L","H","L")
TIME <- c(90,90,30,30,30,30,90,90)
RESPONSE <- c(5.6,5.2,0,0,4.8,4.9,1.2,.9)

DATA <- data.frame(SUBJECT,POSITION,TIME,RESPONSE)
```

I want the rows of DATA which have SUBJECT numbers that are in a vector, V:

```
V <- c(8,10,10)
```

How can I obtain both observations from DATA whose SUBJECT number is in V and have those observations repeated the same number of times as the corresponding SUBJECT number appears in V?

Desired result:

```
SUBJECT <- c(8,8,10,10,10,10)
POSITION <- c("H","L","H","L","H","L")
TIME <- c(90,90,30,30,30,30)
RESPONSE <- c(5.6,5.2,0,0,0,0)

OUT <- data.frame(SUBJECT,POSITION,TIME,RESPONSE)
```

I thought some variation of the %in% operator would do the trick but it does not account for repeated subject numbers in V. Even though a subject number is listed twice in V, I only get one copy of the corresponding rows in DATA.

I could also create a loop and append matching observations but this piece is inside a bootstrap sampler and this option would dramatically increase computation time.

Comment: If you're bootstrapping with DATA staying the same and v changing, you might want to consider data.table, which does fast joining to a subset, like `setDT(DATA); setindex(DATA, SUBJECT); DATA[.(v), on="SUBJECT"]`

Comment: @Frank I cannot run your code. `setindex()` results in the following error:  _Error: could not find function "setindex"_. I'm assuming this is part of the `data.table` library or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If your version of data.table hasn't been updated in a year or so, you might need `set2key` instead. (The name of the function changed is all.)

Answer (score 5):

`merge` is your friend:

```
merge(list(SUBJECT=V), DATA)
#  SUBJECT POSITION TIME RESPONSE
#1       8        H   90      5.6
#2       8        L   90      5.2
#3      10        H   30      0.0
#4      10        L   30      0.0
#5      10        H   30      0.0
#6      10        L   30      0.0
```

As @Frank implies, this logic can be translated to `data.table` or `dplyr` or `sql` of anything else that will handle a left-join.